# Grails plugin cannot access to multidatasources

Tags: grails, grails-orm, datasource

I have a plugin (Let's call its plugin `A`) with option domain entities and one more plugin with obligatory entities (plugin `B`). Plugin `B` also has a definition of 2 datasources (default `dataSource` and `dataSource_redshift`). In my application originally I have dependency on plugin `B` and can use both datasources without any problems. However I have now add plugin `A` as dependecy to my application and entity with default datasource seem like working well, but in case I'm creating such entity:

```
class RedshiftEntity {

    static mapping = {
        datasource "redshift"
        table name: "table", schema: "public"
        id generator: 'assigned', column:'id'
        version false
    }

    ...
    fields
    ...
}
```

On load of application I get such error:

```
Caused by: org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.exceptions.ConfigurationException: DataSource not found for name [dataSource_redshift] in configuration. Please check your multiple data sources configuration and try again.
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.getDatastoreForConnection(HibernateDatastore.java:337)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormEnhancer.getStaticApi(HibernateGormEnhancer.groovy:47)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.registerEntity(GormEnhancer.groovy:139)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.<init>(GormEnhancer.groovy:122)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormEnhancer.<init>(HibernateGormEnhancer.groovy:41)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.initialize(HibernateDatastore.java:414)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.<init>(HibernateDatastore.java:177)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore.<init>(HibernateDatastore.java:188)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1075)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    ... 84 common frames omitted
```

In case I move this entity to plugin `B` - it works great with `dataSource_redshift`. Please, give an idea what am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Grails you are using, but if you have:
Application app
  depends on Plugin B
  depends on Plugin A

You need to change the application's Datasource.groovy to contain the datasource for 'dataSource_redshift' as the application's Datasource.groovy is the file that is used.

Comment: @adamcooney, actualy app already have access to dataSource_redshift without any problems (I have some code that perform direct call to this datasource), but it can not use entity from plugin A which is mapped to dataSource_redshift. So I suppose I already have correctly configured Datasource.groovy here.

Comment: You only need the name of the datasource; change
`static mapping = {
        datasource "dataSource_redshift"
}`

to
`static mapping = {
        datasource "redshift"
}`

This will then look up `dataSource_redshift`.

Comment: @adamcooney yes, I have already found this solution and does not help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root cause of such problem. `Plugin B` have special construction to enable or disable the second data source for apps by there name:

```
switch(app_name) {
    ...
    case 'main_app':
        redshiftEnabled = true 
    ...
}
```

Redshift data source is enabled for my main app, but seems like data sources are not transparent for plugins as I expected. When `plugin B` with data sources are added as a dependency to the main app, other connected to the app plugins are not allowed to access the second data source. I need explicitly enumerate plugins by there personal names in plugin with data sources:

```
switch(app_name) {
    ...
    case 'main_app':
        redshiftEnabled = true
    case 'plugin_A':
        redshiftEnabled = true 
    ...
}
```

I'd rather expect that after plugins are connected to the main app they access data sources with the name of the main app, but seems like it does not so.